# CoffeeScript error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, command-line, coffeescript

Trying to compile a simple coffee script to JS in command line fails with the following error:

```
> ReferenceError: ko is not defined   at Object.<anonymous>
> (/Users/jikku/JS/ko_crashcourse/script.coffee:2:9)   at
> Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jikku/JS/ko_crashcourse/script.coffee:1:1) 
> at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

The coffeescript I am trying to compile:

```
app_model =
  task: ko.observable()
  tasks: ko.observableArray()
  add_task: ->
    @tasks.push @task()
    return

ko.applyBindings app_model
```

- It works fine in [JS2Coffee](http://www.js2coffee.org)
- I used the command: `coffee s.coffee`

Any ideas why?

Comment: as the error says you are trying to access an undefined object: ko. Try to check why it is undefined.

Comment: This is simple `ko` is not defined.

Comment: It sounds like you're transpiling CoffeeScript to JavaScript. The transpiler (sometimes called a compiler) should have some option to allow you to define the external symbols that will exist in the environment where you expect the JavaScript to be run. Add `ko` to that list of symbols.

Comment: Yes, I am transpiring; how can I add the external symbols? via command line parameters? How did js2coffee detect it by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
coffee s.coffee
```

will both compile your coffee file to JavaScript and run it. That is why you are getting your undefined error (knockout isn't available in your file).

Use `-c` to just compile:

```
coffee -c s.coffee
```

(that will output it to `s.js`)

Comment: Oh the default is to compile and run? That was unexpected, probably should have expected from the output. Anyways, thanks!